# Mypy with __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have issues when running mypy on my python package.

The module should have a structure like this:

```
test/
    fileA.py
    fileB.py
    __init__.py
```

where fileA.py contains:

```
class A:
    pass
```

And fileB.py:

```
from fileA import A
class B:
    pass
```

When running mypy I get the following error

```
ubuntu:~/test$ mypy fileA.py fileB.py
fileA.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: 'test.fileA' and 'fileA'
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

This is due to having a `__init__.py` in the package/directory. Removing the file could fix the issue, but I clearly needed it since I am building a python package out of this.

Anyone knows what to do? This is mypy v0.800

Comment: You could change `fileB.py` to `from test.fileA import A` and then execute mypy outside your package as `mypy test/`.

Comment: That works, but wouldn't a package import modules from its own CWD? I see this import test.fileA as it would try to find the package test and not use the one provided in the same directory.

Comment: Think of `test` as your "root" folder.. No matter how deep your modules lie, you always refer back to the root - also no matter which "branch" of folders you your module is in.

Comment: "wouldn't a package import modules from its own CWD" That's not how imports, packages *or* CWD work. CWD is application-global, it is not specific to packages. The import machinery and packages work via a set of import paths, with modules/packages in them identified by fully qualified names.